# Changing the system OS from windows XP to Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I  have a system of IBM with the following specs:

- 1 gb ram
- 40 gb hard
- 2.53ghz processor

It was useless for me but now I want to get skill in linux operating system as its my university project. 
That's why I want to install Ubuntu on my old operating system named above.

I downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu and made a bootable usb using universal usb installer.
But when I boot the pc from usb, usb stop responding.. (light first blink and then stop blinking).

Comment: Try out Lubuntu, it is more suitable for older PCs.

Comment: Did you make sure you have selected the correct boot option from the BIOS?
How did you create your image? Maybe your USB is damaged corrupt?
Try to run fdisk on it.
Tarek

Answer (score 1):

Your specs are not good enough for latest Ubuntu. Even if you manage to install it somehow, you will not be able to expect good performance.

**Lubuntu** is recommended for your 1gb RAM PC.It is based on Ubuntu, uses the same repositories, but specially built for older and weaker machines.

[Lubuntu site](http://lubuntu.net)